# Using Razor Pages, how would I load related data to a div after a user has selected a parent from a dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal, razor-pages

I have an entity called DivisionContacts with an email and a DivisionId foreign key, and I have an Entity called Division with a DivisionId primary key. A user would select a Division from a dropdown menu, such as Childrens Services or Senior Services, and once that division is selected they would then be able to click a button to see all the DivisionContacts email addresses owned by that division in a Bootstrap popup modal. I need to know what the best way to perform this functionality is in Razor Pages.

Here are the entities:

```
    public class Division
{
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Division")]
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DivisionContact> DivisionContacts { get; set; }
}

    public class DivisionContact
{
    public int DivisionContactId { get; set; }

    public int DivisionId { get; set; }

    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    

    public Division Division { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="divisionContactsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Division Contacts</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                @*<div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the button that opens the modal:

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-sm-12" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divisionContactsModal">
Click to see who receives these emails.
    </button>
```

Would I need to use a view model and jquery to perform this kind of functionality? Or would it require a handler method? The button that triggers the modal popup is nested inside another form. Would a handler method work when the button is nested in another form? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax in onchange event to return a Partial view which displays all the DivisionContacts email addresses.

Patial view(_Partial.cshtml located in `Pages` folder):

```
@model IndexModel
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ContactEmail
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.DivisionContacts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactEmail)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@page
@model IndexModel    
<select asp-for="Division.DivisionId" asp-items="ViewBag.Division" 
                                    onchange="DisplayDivisionContact(this)">
    <option>--Choose A Division--</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-sm-12" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divisionContactsModal">
    Click to see who receives these emails.
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="divisionContactsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Division Contacts</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function DisplayDivisionContact(selectObject) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "?handler=DisplayDivisionContact&id=" + selectObject.value,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (res) {
                    $(".modal-body").html(res);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

Backend(Index.cshtml.cs):

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    //here I hard-coded the data for easy testing
    //you can get the data from database
    //List<Division> Divisions =  _context.Division.Include(a=>a.DivisionContacts).ToList();
    List<Division> Divisions = new List<Division>()
    {
        new Division(){
            DivisionId=1,
            DivisionName="Childrens Services",
            DivisionContacts= new List<DivisionContact>()
            {
                new DivisionContact(){DivisionContactId=1,DivisionId=1,ContactEmail="a@qq.com"},
                new DivisionContact(){DivisionContactId=2,DivisionId=1,ContactEmail="b@qq.com"}
            }
        },
        new Division(){
            DivisionId=2,
            DivisionName="Senior Services",
            DivisionContacts= new List<DivisionContact>()
            {
                new DivisionContact(){DivisionContactId=3,DivisionId=2,ContactEmail="c@qq.com"},
                new DivisionContact(){DivisionContactId=4,DivisionId=2,ContactEmail="d@qq.com"}
            }
        }
    };
    public Division Division { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["Division"] = new SelectList(Divisions, "DivisionId", "DivisionName");
    }

    [ViewData]
    public List<DivisionContact> DivisionContacts { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnGetDisplayDivisionContact(int id) 
    {           
        DivisionContacts = Divisions
                    .Where(a => a.DivisionId == id)
                    .FirstOrDefault().DivisionContacts.ToList();
        return new PartialViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "_Partial",
            ViewData = this.ViewData
        };
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]